# Express.JS server gives 'Internal Error' message whenever fs is called in app.get callback

Tags: node.js, express

In my Express.JS/Node.JS server (Running on openshift), whenever the `app.get("*", callback)` callback function is executed, if the function contains any references to fs, instead of serving my data, it serves an `'Internal Error'` error. I have searched up my symptoms, and have found no solution. My code [some parts excluded] is as follows:

```
--> THE REQUIRE STATEMENTS <--
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

--> THE APP.GET AND METHODS IT USES <--
var verify_file = function(file) {
    while (fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
        file = path.join(file, "index.html");
    }
    if (fs.existsSync(file)) {
        if(path.normalize(file).split(path.sep).indexOf(".." > -1)) {
            return 'public_html/e/denied.html';
        } else {
            return path.normalize(file);
        }
    } else {
        return 'public_html/e/missing.html';
    }
}
app.get("*", function(req, res){
    var p = verify_file(path.join('/public_html/' + req.originalUrl));
    var c = fs.readFileSync(p);
    res.send("This should show if it works");
});
```

Whenever I comment out BOTH the `var c` and `var p` references, res.send is called and I see the results.
The directory with this script contains the `public_html` directory, which contains an `index.html` file.
My expected behavior is for "This should show if it works" to be shown when I load the page, and have no errors regarding fs.

Comment: Is there no Exception in the console? Post it. Also, you should **not** use the blocking (`Sync`) family of functions in a callback. Use the regular ones, `readFile` and `exists`.

Comment: Openshift online app console is down so can't figure out how to SSH into the server right now.

Comment: Also, using the nonblocking versions gave me more errors so I switched.

Answer (score 1):

More likely than not, one of the synchronous `fs` methods you are using is throwing an exception and Express is catching it for you. Try wrapping your synchronous `fs` method calls with a try-catch so you can handle the error(s) however you want.

Comment: All of the fs.doSomthingSync methods throw an exception on error. As mscdex says, use try catch. Alternatively use the non sync versions with something like the async module to write neat callback oriented code.